# How can I remove the fields from a document that failed validation with Cerberus?

Tags: python, cerberus

I am using the open source Python data validation library [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/) to validate the structure of a dictionary. I want it to take a partly invalid document and output it without the invalid keys.

For example, for this script:

```
from cerberus import Validator

schema = {'name': {'type': 'string'}, 
          'user_id': {'type': 'integer'}}
document = {'name': 'john doe', 'user_id': 'fdfdfd'}
v = Validator(schema)
v.validated(document)
```

This returns `None` because the validation failed.

Is there a way to get the document with only the validated fields, like this:

```
{'name': 'john doe'}
```

Comment: Please add the current output.

Comment: The output of v.validate(document) is "True"
the v.document attribute contains `{'name': 'john doe', 'wrongkey': 'fdfdfd'}`
the v.errors attribute contains `{'wrongkey': 'must be of integer type'}`

Answer (score 3):

This is a safer solution than @jdoe's, because the structure of the `Validator.errors` property doesn't necessarily correlate to a document's one. But the `document_error_tree` provides such.

```
def remove_invalid_fields(document, errors_tree):
    if errors_tree is None:
        return document
    filtered = {}
    for field, value in document.items():
        if field in errors_tree.descendants:
            continue
        if isinstance(value, Mapping):
            value = remove_invalid_fields(value, errors_tree[field])
        filtered[field] = value
    return filtered

schema = {'name': {'type': 'string'},
          'user_id': {'type': 'integer'}}
document = {'name': 'john doe', 'user_id': 'fdfdfd'}
validator = Validator(schema)

validator(document)
result = remove_invalid_fields(document, validator.document_error_tree)
assert result == {'name': 'john doe'}
```

It also takes errors in subdocuments into account.

Comment: I tried this solution, but unfortunately I am getting error on line `if field in errors_tree.descendants:` `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'descendants'`. However `validator.document_error_tree`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: i amended the propably needed lines to the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
validDoc = {}
for key in document:
    if key not in v.errors:
        validDoc[key] = document[key]
print(validDoc)
```

produces this output:

```
{'name': 'john doe'}
```

Comment: I was hoping that there is something "built-in" that does it. if there isn't - that's what I'll do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the `purge_unknown` option?

```
>>> v = Validator({'foo': {'type': 'string'}}, purge_unknown=True)
>>> v.normalized({'bar': 'foo'})
{}
```

In the example above, `bar` is unknown, hence it is purged. Note that we are using `normalized` here, see [the docs](https://cerberus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/normalization-rules.html).

Comment: That doesn't help me
I am giving the key to the validator, but it's it doesn't match the schema so it doesn't drop it - it's a known field